# macOS Catalina upgrade failed. Can I downgrade to macOS Mojave?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, macos-catalina, macos-mojave, macos-highsierra

I am running an older Mac: iMac 13,1 Intel Core i7 and it is currently running macOS High Sierra (10.13).

A while back I upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15), and lots of apps stopped working, most importantly MS Word and Excel as well as Quicken 2007. This was not acceptable since I want MS Word and Quicken 2007 and do not want to pay every year versions that you are forced to use now. So I restored from backup to High Sierra.

What happens if I downgrade to macOS Mojave (10.14)? Am I going to have similar issues?

I am guessing that it has something to do with 32 bit vs 64 bit, but that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Technically, the term is DOWNGRADE, not UPGRADE.  Yes, you can do this and your 32bit apps will come back to life.  Makes me mad that Apple forced this.  Google "downgrade catalina to mojave" to find more on this topic.

Comment: I believe you may have misunderstood. I upgraded from High Sierra to Catalina and had apps fail. I then restored back down to High Sierra. My question has to do with upgrading now from High Sierra to Mojave. Will there be problems with apps?

Comment: Shouldn't be as long as it is Mojave or anything predating Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted long ago... Anyway, I went from High Sierra to Mojave and all of my 32 bit applications continued to work.